# Jquery Chosen plugin not displaying correctly in internet explorer when coding with Smarty

Tags: internet-explorer, smarty, jquery-chosen

I've been trialling Harvest's Chosen plugin, http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/, which creates a cool select box. It works for most browsers including ie 8+. However when I use the code in Smarty it does not work for Internet Explorer. Even more bizarrely, when I use the HTML source code generated instead of Smarty it works. Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>{$site_title|escape}{if $page_title} - {$page_title|escape}{/if}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Javascript/docsupport/prism.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Javascript/chosen.css">
{literal}
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
    /* fix rtl for demo */
    .chosen-rtl .chosen-drop { left: -9000px; }
  </style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="Javascript/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="Javascript/docsupport/prism.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
{/literal}
</head>
<body>
   <form>
    <div id="wrap">
      <div id="main">

         <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="1">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="United States">United States</option>
            <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
            <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
            <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
            <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
            <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
            <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
            <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
            <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
            <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
            <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
            <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
            <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
            <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
            <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
            <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
            <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
            <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
            <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
            <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
            <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
            <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
            <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
            <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
            <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
          </select>
     {literal}

                <script type="text/javascript">
                      var config = {
                           '.chosen-select'           : {},
                           '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
                           '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
                           '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
                           '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
                                    }
                       for (var selector in config) {
                                $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
                                                    }
                  </script>

      {/literal}
     </div>
   </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This generates the following HTML which works exactly as it should in all browsers...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>{$site_title|escape}{if $page_title} - {$page_title|escape}{/if}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Javascript/docsupport/prism.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Javascript/chosen.css">

  <style type="text/css" media="all">
    /* fix rtl for demo */
    .chosen-rtl .chosen-drop { left: -9000px; }
  </style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="Javascript/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="Javascript/docsupport/prism.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
       <form>
        <div id="wrap">
          <div id="main">
              <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="1">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="United States">United States</option>
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
                <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
                <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
                <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
                <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
                <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
                <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
                <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
                <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
                <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
                <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
                <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
                <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
                <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
                <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
                <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
                <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
                <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
                <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
              </select>



                    <script type="text/javascript">
                          var config = {
                               '.chosen-select'           : {},
                               '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
                               '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
                               '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
                               '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
                                        }
                           for (var selector in config) {
                                    $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
                                                        }
                      </script>

               </div>
            </div>
          </form>
       </body>
    </html>
```

In response to my reply on 25th March, I'm showing Smarty code for my website Looknf.co.uk here which also illustrates that Chosen doesn't work in Internet Explorer. First Index.tpl

```
{assign var="meta_description" value=$app->setting->site_description}
{if $smarty.session.magnify}{assign var="scripts" value='/tjpzoom.js'}{/if}
{include file='header.inc.tpl'}

      <div id="main">

          <div id="div-leftcol">
               <form id="myForm">
                 <span style="position:relative;left:9px;top:5px">
                     <b> Town:</b>
                     <select id="grid" data-placeholder="Select your town" class="chosen-select" style="width:200px;" tabindex="1" onchange="document.location.href='?grid=' + this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value">
                    {html_options options=$categories selected=$grid}
                    </select>
                </span>
                <span style="position:relative;left:9px;top:10px">
                     <b> Business Type:</b>
                     <select name="regions_category_id" id="selectR" data-placeholder="Type what you're looking for..." class="chosen-select" style="width:200px;" tabindex="2" onchange="return findURL(this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value,$grid)">
                     {html_options style="font-size:16px" options=$regions selected=$regions_category_id}
                     </select>
                </span>
               </form>

               <span style="position:relative;top:15px;left:15px;">
                <a href="#" id="try-1" class="try sprited">3 Simple Steps to Success...</a> 
               </span>

               <span style="position:relative;top:30px;left:0px">
                   <a href="{url|escape href='/newsletter_signup.php'}"><img src="images/Newsletter-220.png" title="" alt="Newsletter"></a>
               </span>

               <span style="float:left;position:relative;top:45px;left:20px;">
                   <a href="#" id="try-2">Why Look No Further?</a> 
               </span>

               <span style="position:relative;top:60px;left:34px;">  
                   <a href="{url|escape href='/get_pixels.php'}"><img src="images/Advertiser-Offer13.gif" style="width:150px;outline:grey solid thin;" id="qs_1" name="qs_1" title="" alt="Offer"></a>
               </span>

          </div>


          <div id="div-gridmain">
             {foreach item=grids from=$rows}
               {foreach item=grid from=$grids}
                  <map name="grid_{$grid->id}">{$grid->map()}</map>
                  <img src="{$grid->url()|escape}" usemap="#grid_{$grid->id}" width="{$grid->width|escape}" height="{$grid->height|escape}" alt="" border="0" />
               {/foreach}
             {/foreach}
          </div>

          {include file='footer.tpl'}

        </div>



         {literal}
          <!-- floating page sharers Start -->
           <!--[if !IE]> -->
           <style>
            #pageshare {position:fixed; bottom:15%; margin-left:1220px; float:right; border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;background-color:#E0E2DC;padding:0 0 2px 0;z-index:5000;}
           </style>
           <![endif]-->
           <!--[if IE]>
           <style>
            #pageshare {position:fixed; bottom:15%; margin-left:1205px; float:right; border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;background-color:#E0E2DC;padding:0 0 2px 0;z-index:5000;}
           </style>
           <![endif]-->
           <style>
            #pageshare .sbutton {float:left;clear:both;margin:5px 5px 0 5px;z-index:5000;}
.fb_share_count_top {width:48px !important;z-index:5000;}
.fb_share_count_top, .fb_share_count_inner {-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;z-index:5000;}
            .FBConnectButton_Small, .FBConnectButton_RTL_Small {width:49px !important; -moz-border-radius:3px;/*bs-fsmsb*/-webkit-border-radius:3px;z-index:5000;}
.FBConnectButton_Small .FBConnectButton_Text {padding:2px 2px 3px !important;-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;font-size:8px;z-index:5000;}
          </style>


          <div id='pageshare'>
              <div style="clear:both;font-size: 16px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;color: #000000;z-index:5000;">
Share
              </div>
              <div class='sbutton' id='fb'>
                   <a name="fb_share" type="box_count" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a>
                   <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
              </div>
              <div class='sbutton' id='tweet'>
                   <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://looknf.co.uk/" data-counturl="http://looknf.co.uk" data-lang="en" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>
                   <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
              </div>
              <div class='sbutton' id='gplusone'>
                   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
                   <g:plusone size="tall" href="http://www.looknf.co.uk"></g:plusone>
              </div>
              <div class='sbutton' id='friend'>
                   <a href='/tell_a_friend.php'><img src="images/email_friend.png" outline="none" border-style="none"></a>
              </div>
          </div>



          <script type="text/javascript">
                  var config = {
                     '.chosen-select'           : {},
                     '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
                     '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
                     '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
      '               .chosen-select-width'     : {width:"100%"}
                 }
                   for (var selector in config) {
                      $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
                 }
          </script>
          {/literal}



          </div>

{include file='wz_tooltip.inc.tpl'}
{include file='footer.inc.tpl'}
```

Now header.inc.tpl

```
{assign var='stylesheets' value='/styleNEW.css'}
{include file='html.inc.tpl'}
<body{$body_attr}>
<div id="wrap">
{include file='our.logo.tpl'}
```

I'm not putting in every include here, but here is html.inc.tpl

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="{$language_code|escape|default:'en'}" lang="{$language_code|escape|default:'en'}">
<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="http://www.looknf.co.uk/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.looknf.co.uk/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
{if trim($meta_description)}
  <meta name="description" content="{$meta_description|escape}" />
{else}
  <meta name="description" content="{$app->settings->meta_tags->description|escape|default:"Michael Mallick"}" />
{/if}
{if $meta_robots}
  <meta name="robots" content="{$meta_robots|escape}" />
{else}
  <meta name="robots" content="{$app->meta_tags->robots|escape|default:"index, follow"}" />
{/if}
  <meta name="copyright" content="{$app->meta_tags->copyright|escape|default:"Look No Further"}" />
  <meta name="author" content="{$app->meta_tags->author|escape|default:"Michael Mallick"}" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="{$app->meta_tags->keywords|escape|default:"look no further"}" />
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans+Std+Light&subset=latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  {foreach item=stylesheet from=$stylesheets}
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{url|escape href=$stylesheet}" />
  {/foreach} 
  {foreach item=script from=$scripts}
     <script type="text/javascript" src="{url|escape href=$script}"></script>
  {/foreach}
  <title>{$site_title|escape}{if $page_title} - {$page_title|escape}{/if}</title>

  {literal}

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="Javascript/jsRollover.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Javascript/docsupport/prism.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Javascript/chosen.css">
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
    /* fix rtl for demo */
    .chosen-rtl .chosen-drop { left: -9000px; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="Javascript/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="Javascript/docsupport/prism.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<!-- <script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
      '.chosen-select'           : {},
      '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
      '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
      '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
      '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
      $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }
  </script> -->

  <script>
    $(function() {
    $("#selectR").change(function () {
       var str = "";
       var reg = $(this).val();
       var grid = $("#grid").val();
       findURL(reg,grid);
          });
       });
  </script>

  <script src="Javascript/findURL.js"></script>


  {/literal}
</head>
```

Comment: If the second block of code is the final output, smarty is not working properly, notice how there is still smarty code not processed, like <body{$body_attr}>

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. The reason {$body_attr} hasn't processed is because I stripped out much of the code. However this isn't the reason Chosen isn't working in Internet Explorer. Even with the unprocessed Smarty the HTML works.

Comment: Then please post the real code that smarty generates, not just a stripped version of the template.

Comment: What you saw previously was the actual code generated by Smarty. What I meant by stripping out is that I originally had more code around this and reduced it just to focus on Chosen. I inadvertently left in {$body_attr} but had taken out the assignment of the variable. Anyway I corrected that, and posted the new Smarty and HTML

Comment: Then again, if you have smarty tags in the final source code, that means that smarty is not working. Can you post the lines of code you use to invoke smarty and process the template? If smarty were working you wouldn't need to manually remove things like {$body_attr}, because there wouldn't be there

Comment: Apologies @Borgtex for not getting back sooner. You are right, but it was down to something I did when I stripped out the code. If you look at the code generated by our site [link](http://looknf.co.uk) you will see this now works. I'll add the Smarty for parts of this to my original question. You will see however the Chosen boxes for Town and Business do not work in internet explorer.